# Test con Rspec de create controller Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, test, rspec

Quiero realizar el test del create de mi controller, he realizado la parte de cuando el 'save' se ejecuta (@holiday.save), pero no se como hacer para que me falle el 'save' e ingrese al 'else' de mi controlador create. El controlador es el siguiente:

```
  def create
    @holiday = Holiday.new(holiday_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @holiday.save
      format.html { redirect_to holidays_path, notice: 'Holiday was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @holiday }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @holiday.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end
  end
```

El test que he realizado y funciona es el siguiente: (necesito agregar la parte de cuando falla el 'save')

```
# Test suite for New holidays
describe 'New /holidays' do
context 'New holidays' do
  before do
    admin = create(:user_admin)
    signin(admin.cui, admin.password)
  end

  it 'create a holidays' do
    visit '/holidays/new'
    fill_in('holiday_day', with: DateTime.now)
    fill_in('holiday_description', with: 'SpecialityDescription1')
    click_button('Guardar')
    expect(page).to have_http_status(:ok)
  end
end
```

end

Codigo del modelo holiday:

```
class Holiday < ApplicationRecord
 validates :day, presence: true

 # Verifico si el dia seleccionado es feriado
 def self.feriado?(fecha)
   Holiday.where('day = ?', fecha).pluck(:description)
 end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

La prueba es muy similar, solo tienes que omitir información que requiera el modelo `Holiday` para crearse. Por ejemplo, asumiendo que `holiday_day` sea un campo obligatorio (i.e. `validates :holiday_day, presence: :true`), podrías utilizar esta prueba para probar tanto un *save* exitoso como uno fallido (i.e. el `else`):

```
describe 'POST #create' do
  before do
    admin = create(:user_admin)
    signin(admin.cui, admin.password)
  end

  context 'when correct information is provided' do
    it 'creates a holiday' do
      visit '/holidays/new'
      fill_in('holiday_day', with: DateTime.now)
      fill_in('holiday_description', with: 'SpecialityDescription1')
      click_button('Guardar')
  
      expect(page).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end

  context 'when inccorrect information is provided' do
    it "doesn't create a holiday" do
      visit '/holidays/new'
      fill_in('holiday_description', with: 'SpecialityDescription1')
      click_button('Guardar')
  
      expect(page).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Tengo realizado exactamente lo que me pasaste e incluso con las validaciones del modelo y me arroja lo siguiente al correr los test: Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
       expected the response to have status code :unprocessable_entity (422) but it was :ok (200)

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código del modelo `Holiday` y el controlador completo?

Comment: Si, ahi lo agregue al codigo. El controller create de Holiday ya lo inclui anteriormente.